# Distribution of Executable jar file in netbeans

Tags: swing, netbeans

I have created a database desktop application using netbeans. Netbeans creates a jar file in the project folder. When I run it, it works fine.
The problem is when I take that jar file outside the project folder and then try to run it, it shows an exception of `org.sqlite.jdbc`. This exception keeps on striking until I close the process using Windows task manager but it is not running.

Comment: *"..it shows an exception of `org.sqlite.jdbc`."* What exception? Always copy/paste error and exception output! I might guess it is a class-path issue, but I don't like guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I have found a solution here http://arunasujith.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html?m=1.

Answer (score 2):

In `dist` folder, you will find three things :

1. the `.jar` file of your project
2. a `lib` folder
3. Readme.txt

Make sure that when you take your `.jar` file outside the project folder, take the lib folder as well.

The lib folder contains all the libraries and jar files you've used in your project and are essential to make the jar file run.
Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: Sir is there any way to combine all the library to the same jar file and distribute as a single jar file

Comment: *"is there any way to combine all the library to the same jar file"* Doing so typically breaks the distribution agreement of the library Jars & destroys the digital signatures of them. Care must also be taken to replicate the manifests of the dependant Jars. *"distribute as a single jar file"* The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). It makes the app. available across a network or internet from a singl click. It's a little hassle for the developer to set up, but very easy for the end user.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/java/ I use this for making my Jar Files, a windows executable files.

If Useful, Please accept the answer.!